# Retrain tensorflow model for additional categories

Tags: tensorflow

I'm building a program using tensorflow image classification. I got [tensorflow](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow) from github, and what I know is pretty much, how to run classify_image.py!

What I want to do is have an option to train the model in a simple manner. For example, the model knows "keys", but I want to train it for "HouseKeys" which have a fancy keyfob or something. Is there some sort of script I can use to say "take these 20 images and learn HouseKeys" so the model can distinguish "keys" from "HouseKeys"?

Excuse my nooblines, and thank you in advance!

Edit: Obviously, it is very important that the model keeps its knowledge of all the other categories it knew previously, since being able to recognize only "HouseKeys" is absolutely useless.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this. However, it will need some adjustments probably.

I don't know exactly the script you are referring to but I'm going to assume you have at least two python files. One is the actual neural network and the other one handles training and evaluation.

The first thing you need to do is make sure the neural network can handle new classes. Look for something like this:

```
input_y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, classes], name="input_y")
```

A lot of the time, if you see tensors who's name contains *x* (`input_x` for example) they refer to the data, the training input.

Tensors that have *y* in their name, like the example above, usually refer to the labels.

The code above says `input_y` is a tensor (think array for the moment) of type `float32`, of variable length (`None` from `[None, classes]`) but with each element of dimension `classes`.

If `classes` was 3, `input_y` could look like this:

```
[[0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0]]
```

Just as well, it could look like this:

```
[[0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]]
```

Although the length can vary, we must always have as elements a size 3 (`classes`)
As for the meaning, `[0, 0, 1]` for example means this is a label for class 2, because we have 1 at index 2 ( look for one hot notation ).

The point of this is, a neural network with this sort of input can learn up to 3 classes. Each input for the tensor *x* has associated a label from the tensor *y* and the labels from *y* can be either 0, 1 or 2 in one hot notation.

With something like this, you can learn for example "keys", "HouseKeys" and "CarKeys" but you will not be able to add "OfficeKeys" for example.

So, first step is make sure your network can learn the maximum number of labels you want.

It does not have to learn them all at once. This brings us to point 2:

Take a look [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#Saver). This is the documentation for the Tensorflow Saver class. This will allow you to save and load models.

For your problem, this translates into training the model on a 2 class data set, saving it, generating a 3 class data set, loading the previously saved model and train on the new data set. It will have the same *"knowledge"* (weights) as the model you saved, but it will start to adjust them to fit the third class.

But for this, you will need to make sure the network can, from the begining, handle 3 classes.

Hope this helps!